# JList only updating on first insertion

Tags: java, swing, jlist

This is my first attempt at a decent GUI for a Java app and I needed to use [JLists](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/JList.html) with custom [ListModels](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/ListModel.html) in order to represent certain structures.

```
//The 2 below structures implement the ListModel interface, using an internal
//ArrayList, in order to be used as
//a model for 2 different JLists in my GUI.
private PropertyList propertiesList = new PropertyList();
private SelectedProperties selProperties = new SelectedProperties();
//and these are the two JLists they are the models for
private javax.swing.JList Properties_JList;
private javax.swing.JList SelectedProperties_JList;
```

Here I populate my first JList via a stream:

```
private void OpenFile_MenuItemActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                  
    final JFileChooser fc = new JFileChooser();
    fc.setCurrentDirectory(null);
    int returnVal = fc.showOpenDialog(this);

    if (returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
        File file = fc.getSelectedFile();
        this.Properties_JList.setModel(propertiesList);
        this.propertiesList.AddFromFile(file);
    } else {
        //...
    }
}
```

which happens to be working perfectly fine. I import a few entries by reading the file and they are all displayed as expected in a .toString() representation.

The problem is the second JList:

```
private void AddToSelected_JButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {

    Property p = (Property) this.Properties_JList.getSelectedValue();
    this.SelectedProperties_JList.setModel(selProperties);
    this.selProperties.InsertProperty(p);
    this.SelectedProperties_JList.revalidate();
}
```

Which appears to be displaying **only** the very first item I attempt to add to it through the above button event, and I have no idea why. I considered moving both .setModel(...) calls right after the form's initComponents() call but if I do that none of the lists gets populated, at all.
Logging messages made it clear that the internal structures **are** getting populated, but even though they are both respective ListModels for my JLists, one of them isn't working as expected.

A sufficient portion of the code is generated by Netbeans and I have spent hours looking up the API but still have trouble finding out what I'm doing wrong. Any ideas?

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: Where's `SelectedProperties` and what does `InsertProperty` do??

Comment: @MadProgrammer in a different package and the operation adds elements to its internal ArrayList. The program compiles and runs without Exceptions when I try the above.

Comment: @JohnAthanasiou does the model fire a interval added event?

Comment: @MadProgrammer Not really. I wasn't sure on how to do the implementation of ModelList so I did only fundamentally required things by the interface. Still, I did the same thing with both implementations used in the JLists.

Comment: @JohnAthanasiou without event notification from the model, how is the list suppose to,know it has to update itself?

Comment: Please learn java naming conventions and stick to them.

Comment: _I did only fundamentally required things_ - notification **is** fundamentally required :-) I would suggest you start with reading a basic tutorial (f.i. the on referenced in the swing tag wiki) and maybe at first stick to the default model implementation. Or at least look into the code of the default implementation to get an idea of what your custom model needs to do.